# SQL Parameters, How to give * (ALL) a default parameter?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a query:

```
 SELECT Job,Age,Name + + Surname AS FullName
```

Now I am filtering (in ssrs) per full Name. How do I set a default value in the full name drop down field to show all candidates by default?

Drop down field looks as follows:

```
EVERYONE
JON
Patric
KELLY
STEVE
```

Comment: Hi tommy, I'm working on SSRS here I mentioned about drop down, please ignore the drop down mention

Answer (score 1):

You can pullback your data similiar to the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT OrderBy=2,FilterValue=SurName, Job,Age,Name + + Surname AS FullName
 UNION
 SELECT OrderBy=1,FilterValue=NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL + + '<ALL>' AS FullName
)
ORDER BY
    OrderBy,FullName
```

Then send in the FilterValue into your filter with a where clause similiar to:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE
    (@FilterValue IS NULL) OR (SurName = @FilterValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new multi-value parameter

Create a new dataset:

```
select Name + Surname as FullName
from MyTable
```

Set default of new parameter as query > new dataset

Set available to the same

In your main dataset, use:

```
select <columns>
from MyTable
where Name + Surname in(@NewParameter)
```

Comment: Thanks! and could you please advice about the default value that will generate all users (*)

Comment: @AfricanHeart That is literally what I just did

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
WHERE upper(Name) = upper(@InParm) OR @InParm = '*'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, however could you please explain what you've answered?

Comment: @AfricanHeart -- what don't you understand?  This is a where statement with an `OR` operator.